# ¿por qué no se ven los decimales en variable tipo float?

Tags: c, float

Estoy tratando de que se muestre el valor completo de un decimal ya que solo se imprime con decimales cero por ej: 68 / 8 debe dar 8.50 si se usa %.2f ó 8.500000 si se usa %f, pero no se que pasa que solo se muestra 8.000000 como si tratara de redondearlo

El problema me sale al sacar un promedio asi que decidí extraer el problema para ver que pasaba, al final hice este simple código

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float division = 68 / 8;

    printf("\n probando a ver si imprime los decimales correctos %f \n", division); 

    return 0;
}
```

pero como digo, solo muestra 8.000000 en vez de 8.500000  lo mismo pasa si pongo %.2f me sale 8.00 en vez de 8.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que 68 y 8 son enteros el resultado sera otro entero, para solucionar esto puedes adicionarle el punto decimal a uno de ellos:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float division = 68.0 / 8;

    printf("\n probando a ver si imprime los decimales correctos %f \n", division); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: asi es, tienes razon, esas cosas llaman la atención cuando uno viene de python y javascript. cosas a tener en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi, resulta que  c necesita que al menos 1 de los valores a dividir sean de tiplo float o double, si se quiere dividir como el ejemplo 68/8 debería ser 68.0/8  ó bien 68/8.0  ó tambien 68.0/8.0  en esos casos el resultado si es 8.500000